# How can I evaluate an ecmascript module from a shell script?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm turning my .js files into .mjs files but ran into an issue.

I use a JS function from a shell script as such:

```
$ node --eval "require(\"./foo.js\").bar($a, $b)"
```

After turning it into `foo.mjs`, running:

```
$ node --experimental-modules --eval "import foo from \"./foo.mjs\"; foo.bar($a, $b)"
```

yields

```
[eval]:1
import foo from "./foo.mjs"; foo.bar(, )
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

```
$ node --experimental-modules foo.mjs
```

does nothing or prints "Hello World" if I add a `console.log`. I need to run its `bar()` function with parameters but don't want to add an intermediate script for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the type of the input with the option [`--input-type`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--input-type):

> This configures Node.js to interpret `--eval` or `STDIN` input as CommonJS or as an ES module. Valid values are `commonjs` or `module`. The default is `commonjs` unless `--experimental-default-type=module` is used.

So do:

```bash
node --input-type=module --eval "import foo from \"./foo.mjs\"; foo.bar($a, $b)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick solution! ChatGPT failed me. You did not :D